# Setting up a dedicated server for Beyoncode Laravel Websockets

Tags: php, laravel, websocket

I have been working on this one for almost a week now. I am trying to build a standalone websockets server that can cater multiple clients at the same time. So far I am able to publish to the websocket server. My only problem is the listener on client website.

I am using [this](https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/getting-started/installation) laravel package for my websockets server. and nginx for my web server

This is what I have so far:

so my websocket server is hosted in a dedicated VPS under the domain `web-sockets.live`

this is my nginx config.

```
server {
  root /var/www/html/wss/public;
  index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

  server_name web-sockets.live;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
  }

  location /app/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6001/app/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }

  location /apps/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6001/apps/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }


  location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
  }

  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
  }


  listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/web-sockets.live/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/web-sockets.live/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

this is my `broadcast.php` file configuration

```
 'pusher' => [
        'driver' => 'pusher',
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
            'useTLS' => true,
            'encrypted' => true,
            'host' => 'https://web-sockets.live',
            'port' => 6001,
            'verify' =>true,
            'scheme' => env('PUSHER_SCHEME'),
            'curl_options' => [
                'CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST' => 0,
                'CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER' => 0,
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

and this is my `websockets.php` config file

```
'apps' => [
    [
        'id' => app1,
        'name' => app1Name,
        'key' => app1Key,
        'secret' => app1Secret,
        'capacity' => null,
        'enable_client_messages' => false,
        'enable_statistics' => true,
    ],

    [
        'id' => app2,
        'name' => app2Name,
        'key' => app2Key,
        'secret' => app2Secret,
        'capacity' => null,
        'enable_client_messages' => false,
        'enable_statistics' => true,
    ],
],
```

I can receive the data on the laravel websockets statistics page, but the client website does not receive the data. I am also getting an error on the console on client side.

`WebSocket connection to 'wss://web-sockets.live/app/app2Key?protocol=7&client=js&version=7.4.0&flash=false' failed:`